# JavaScript regular expression to find table names with alias in SQL code

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a very large SQL query. I am trying to scrape tables names using javascript out of SQL query. (I provide SQL query in a text file as input)

```
  select t1.name, t1.id, t1.address, t2.units,t2.sale
  from SCHMEA1.candy_customers_azim_056 as t1
  inner join SCHEMA1.candy_sales_history_set t2
    on (t1.custid = t2.ORIGTN_ACCT_NO)
```

What could be the regular expression to achieve something like this ?

```
Tables:
candy_customers_azim_056 as t1
candy_sales_history_set t2
```

Comment: Have you tried anything yet? Have you put your example text into regex101.com to see if you can work it out that way? Are you looking for just the regex, or are you looking for something that can help you to get the alias' to begin with?

Comment: Maybe like this: `candy_[a-z0-9_]*\s(as\s)?t[0-9]`

Comment: @Ajaypayne I have been trying something like this  https://regex101.com/r/73a5GA/6

Comment: Do you consider queries like: `select * from table1, table2`?

Answer (score 4):

```
(from|join)\s+\w+\.((\w*)[as ]+(\w+))
```

should return what you're looking for in the second capture group.

Comment: this is helpful

Comment: What about next case: `left join candy_sales_history_set4`?

Answer (score 0):

You may try this one as well:

```
/(from|join)\s+(\w+\.)?(\w+)(\s+as)?(\s+\w+)?/gmi
```

You can see examples [here](https://regex101.com/r/av7fpW/3).